# android:How can I change My Background color from method outside class

Tags: android

I got a code for changing BackGroud color of my activity through java code

```
View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
view.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

and I have a public class in which I am defining all common methods

```
    public class MyClass {
public static void myToast(String msg , Context context)
{
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
    Toast.makeText(context, msg, duration).show();
}

public void setBackGroundColor(int color)
{
    // View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
            //view.setBackgroundColor(color);
}

    }
```

how I can pass the 'this' in my method call ?(for using this.getWindow().getDecorView())
is it('this') same as context?
color is int type?
I am totally confused about it 
answers and advices are needed
Thanks in advance

Comment: If I understood what you mean correctly... `this` is referencing an `Activity` so your method should just take an Activity as its argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how I can pass the 'this' in my method call?

`this` means current Activity context so you should add second Parameter to `setBackGroundColor`  as Activity :

```
public void setBackGroundColor(int color,Activity activity)
{
    View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

Comment: @Dev : pass hex-code as String then use `Color.parse(hex-code)` to pass color code to setBackgroundColor method

Answer (score 0):

You can set your hex-code for color through your layout which is .xml file.

If you want to change your background as an image, decor such you have mentioned above in your code; you can implement

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.drawableName);
```

And yes Color is an int type. You can also use your syntax this way:

```
public void setBackGroundColor(Color color){
}
```